# How to set a default selected option in Blazor .net7 from a parameter?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-7.0

I have a dropdown (HTML select) that I populate as a child component via the parent component (index.razor) and, while I can get all the options to display perfectly and get the selected item, I can't seem to set an initial value from the same parent. I've tried several methods and, what works in javascript easily, does not work in Blazor (.Net7).  Basically, I wish to build a custom dropdown/select control component, but would like to have it pre-select one of the options (if desired by the caller).
This should be a simple task, but I'm at a loss. see code below:

dropdown.razor.cs (code behind):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace ComboTest.Components;

public partial class Dropdown
{
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<Option> GetSelection { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public required List<Option> Options { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Id { get; set; } = "";

    [Parameter]
    public string CSSclass { get; set; } = "";

    [Parameter]
    public string InitialValue { get; set; } = "";


    private Option Selection { get; set; } = new Option();

    public string? SelectedValue { get; set; } = "";

    async void SelectionChanged()
    {
        Selection = Options.Find(e => e.Value == SelectedValue);
        await GetSelection.InvokeAsync(Selection);
    }

    public class Option
    {
        public Option(string? value = "", string? name = "", string? style = "" )
        {
            Value = value;
            Name = name;
            Style = style;
        }
        public string? Value { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? Style { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Dropdown.razor markup:

```
<select @bind="@SelectedValue" @bind:after="SelectionChanged" id="@Id" class="@CSSclass">
    @foreach (var opt in Options)
    {
        <option value="@opt.Value" selected="@(InitialValue==opt.Value)" class="@opt.Style">@opt.Name</option> //this doesn't work
    }
</select>
```

And the Index.razor page (parent):

```
@page "/"
@using ComboTest.Components

<Dropdown Options="options" GetSelection="getSelection" Id="mydropdown" CSSclass="form-select ddstyle1" InitialValue="3"></Dropdown>
<br />
<p>You selected:</p>
<p>@selection.Value</p>
<p>@selection.Name</p>


@code {
    List<Dropdown.Option> options = new List<Dropdown.Option>() {
        new Dropdown.Option("1", "Fred", "style3"),
        new Dropdown.Option("2", "Joe", "style1"),
        new Dropdown.Option("3", "Jana", "style2"),
        new Dropdown.Option("4", "Mary", "style1"),
        new Dropdown.Option("5", "Howard", "style3") };

    Dropdown.Option selection = new Dropdown.Option();

    public void getSelection(Dropdown.Option option)
    {
        selection = option;
    }

}
```

In this example, I wish to set the selected option to be of value "3" with the name "Jana"

Answer (score 2):

As I'd put this together for you before you answered your own question, here's a different implementation.

I've taken a few liberties with your code and done some refactoring.

1. `Dropdown`` is now a fairly normal inpout control implementation with binding.
2. I've updated Option so that Value is now an int - that's what it looks like in your code.
3. setting the default value is now done in the parent.  The binding within `Dropdown` will do `Selected` for you unless the value is 0.

Here's the refactored `Dropdown`

```cs
<select @bind:get="@Value" @bind:set="SelectionChanged" class="@CSSclass">

    @if(this.Value == 0)
    {
        <option selected disabled value="0">@this.NullText</option>
    }

    @foreach (var opt in Options)
    {
        <option value="@opt.Value" class="@opt.Style">@opt.Name</option>
    }

</select>

@code {
    [Parameter] public int Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<int> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string CSSclass { get; set; } = "";
    [Parameter] public IEnumerable<Option> Options { get; set; } = Enumerable.Empty<Option>();
    [Parameter] public string NullText { get; set; } = " -- Choose a Value -- ";

    async Task SelectionChanged(int value)
    {
        await this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
    }

    public class Option
    {
        public Option(int value =0, string? name = "", string? style = "")
        {
            Value = value;
            Name = name;
            Style = style;
        }
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? Style { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's the demo page.  It uses binding to `_selectedOptionValue` and the `:after` handler to do the option lookup whenever the value changes.

```cs
@page "/"

<Dropdown Options="options" CSSclass="form-select" @bind-Value="_selectedOptionValue" @bind-Value:after="this.OnSelectionChanged"></Dropdown>

<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="this.SetDefault">Set default to Jana</button>
</div>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>@(_selection?.Value.ToString() ?? "Not Selected")</pre>
    <pre>@(_selection?.Name ?? "Not Selected")</pre>

</div>


@code {
    private int _selectedOptionValue = 0;

    private Dropdown.Option? _selection;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // make sure we have _selection set correctly
        OnSelectionChanged();
    }

    // Updates _selection based on the control's return value
    private void OnSelectionChanged()
    {
        _selection = options.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Value == _selectedOptionValue);
    }

    // demo to show setting the default manually
    private void SetDefault()
    {
        _selectedOptionValue = 3;
        OnSelectionChanged();
    }

    List<Dropdown.Option> options = new List<Dropdown.Option>() {
        new Dropdown.Option(1, "Fred", "style3"),
        new Dropdown.Option(2, "Joe", "style1"),
        new Dropdown.Option(3, "Jana", "style2"),
        new Dropdown.Option(4, "Mary", "style1"),
        new Dropdown.Option(5, "Howard", "style3") };
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was so close: The answer was simple and I just needed to check first render of the component, then assign the value, then fire the selectionchanged event as so:

```
protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            SelectedValue = InitialValue;
            SelectionChanged();
        }
    }
```

Also had to remove the following attribute from the select option:

```
 selected="@(InitialValue==opt.Value)"
```

as this won't work with a bound element (e.g. using @bind )
so it would look like so:

```
<select @bind="@SelectedValue" @bind:after="SelectionChanged" id="@Id" class="@CSSclass">
    @foreach (var opt in Options)
    {
        <option value="@opt.Value" class="@opt.Style">@opt.Name</option>
    }
</select>
```